# Do reviewers need to be domain experts?

Tags: discussion

I just got this audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/9730706

And since I apparently have failed it, now I have a 7-day ban. I'm not complaining that there is a 7-day ban; I understand that's how the system works starting from my prior review state. But I question this specific audit, in that unless you are a CSS expert, it seems like it is a legitimate answer. Is it the right answer? I don't know. Is it an attempt to correctly answer? It seems to be - maybe if I was an expert in CSS I could understand why it is a wrong answer, or a bad answer.

I'm not sure I am a domain expert in any domain, but I am, like most people, more conversant/fluent in some things than in other things. Should I only review things where I do know the answer?

IMO this is a poor audit example. Without being an expert in CSS, this suggestion seems like a legitimate thing that could work. Should I have put it in a fiddle and tested it before making a review choice?

I'm not trying to be difficult here, I'm just trying to understand what exactly SO expects from reviewers. Lately, the audit system is mostly discouraging me from participating, because it's beginning to feel like I'm spending my limited free time contributing in the form of reviews, but now I've made a wrong turn somewhere and wandered into a minefield.

Maybe I just need to press "Skip" more liberally than I do - and that would be fine if it's the right course of action. I'm just trying to determine what the expectations are so I can meet them better.

I have opted not to tag disputed-review-audits here, because maybe I'm off-base and this audit is fine, and it's my understanding that is buggy.

Comment: It's low-quality, even VLQ, as it's extremely short and unclear, so NAN (with confidence declaring the post is perfectly neutral, commenting or editing is a waste of time, and noone else should review this) is obviously wrong. For context, I'm not a domain-expert either, but I'm confident flagging, downvoting and commenting that one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [(deleted) late answer (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32819203)

> You have to try to give the height to the middle content in the percentage with margin bottom

to the question [make div's height the rest of the page on responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32819115)

is low-quality, even VLQ, as it's extremely short and unclear (and devoid of useful information), so "No Action Needed" (with confidence declaring the post is perfectly neutral, commenting or editing is a waste of time, and noone else should review this) is obviously wrong.
For context, I'm not a domain-expert either, but I'm confident flagging, downvoting and commenting that one.

And if you are in any doubt, yes, *please* "Skip", that's always right ([There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)).
All queues but the CVQ (and maybe triage / Needs Improvement) are constantly hovering near empty anyway, so someone else will get around to review it who hopefully knows what to do soon enough anyway.

Comment: Triage is fine; LQP is a little less happy these days (but the OP only has enough for Triage, FP, and LA anyway).

Answer (score 5):

A certain amount of domain knowledge would probably help in some cases, but reviews are meant to be there to see if you're paying attention. Everybody gets reviews (yes, even moderators) and (speaking from personal experience here) do fail them too.

However, I think you've already hit on the solution:

> Maybe I just need to press "Skip" more liberally than I do

On all reviews, whether they are audits or not, if in doubt, "Skip".